# how to parse integer array to json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, database, parsing

this code convert integer array to json. The objective is helper insert into on database.

```
const list = [
'101',  '1922', '2205',
'2495', '2568']

const jsonResult = `{${list}}`
```

output

```
'{101,1922,2205,2495,2568}'
```

Answer (score 1):

your list variable is not json, you have to change the data types of every single index, your solution is like below:

```
const list = [
    '101', '1922', '2205',
    '2495', '2568']

const changeToNumber = () => {
    let result = []
    list.forEach(item => {
        result = [...result, parseInt(item)]
    })
    return result
}

console.log(changeToNumber())
```

Answer (score 0):

x = JSON.stringify(list);

x =>> list JSON STRING